# Can I reset an HP p-class enhanced blade chassis iLO to defaults manually?

Tags: hp, blade-server, ilo, hardware

I just came into possession of a p-class HP BladeSystem enhanced chassis with eight BL25p blades and two CGESM interconnects. I didn't get a SUVI cable so I can't interact wit the blades directly. I don't know what the chassis iLO ip address or password information is, and haven't been able to determine this through any combination of resetting the iLO panel on the back of the chassis and packet sniffing via wireshark.

Is there a way to reset iLO on this particular chassis so I can communicate with the blades while I wait on delivery of a new SUVI cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the iLO to defaults by removing the NVRAM battery and resetting the server settings to default. You may need to short the connector or press a drain button for 30 seconds to clear it.

The default settings should be printed on a sticker affixed to the chassis of each blade server.

iLOs are configured for DHCP by default, so you can capture those with wireshark, or if your environment supports dynamic DNS, iLO will register its default hostname.